# Between two datestime in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a reservation system in php and i have a table(field_data_field_dateres) that has two fields field_dateres_value(start date) and field_dateres_value2(end date). I want to find that if conflict occurs between reservation.
Currently table has a record like this[image]

currently i am writing query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `field_data_field_dateres` WHERE field_dateres_value>='2014-02-14 20:15:00' and field_dateres_value2<='2014-02-14 20:30:00';
```

where 2014-02-14 20:15:00,2014-02-14 20:30:00 will come from php side. But its returning empty record. thanks for any help.

Comment: your end date column has `2014-02-14 21:00:00` which does not satisfy the 2nd condition `field_dateres_value2<='2014-02-14 20:30:00'`

Comment: @anurupr Upvoted your comment bro. Such quick eyes :)

Comment: @anurupr thanks i have tried this now and it seems to be working SELECT * FROM `field_data_field_dateres` WHERE '2014-02-14 20:15:00'>=field_dateres_value and '2014-02-14 20:30:00'<=field_dateres_value2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to find times overlapping (conflicting), the query you want is probably instead;

```
SELECT * FROM `field_data_field_dateres` 
WHERE field_dateres_value  < '2014-02-14 20:30:00' 
  AND field_dateres_value2 > '2014-02-14 20:15:00';
```

Note that the end time is compared to your new time slot's start time, and the start time is compared to your new time slot's end time. This will return all time windows in the database that overlap with your new range.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c3de/1).